# How do I properly identify the language using the URL in this case? How do I set my rewrite rule for that?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a page that runs in more than one language. The english version of that webpage should be accessed through `http://www.example.com/en`.

The problem is that at the moment, I am doing something like this: `http://www.example.com/lang=en` because it seems a bit more 'bullet proof' to use`$_GET` instead of extracting the language code out of an url that could be `http://www.example.com/en/my-great-article/#main?query=var`

Is that correct – is `$_GET` suited better for that kind of task?

Another problem is the use of rewrites to turn `http://www.example.com/lang=en` into `http://www.example.com/en`.
At the moment I am trying it like this through my `.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /*?lang=en /en
```

That is not working *at all*, why?
Also note that the path `/en` does not actually exist on the server, so I am really confused on how to go about that?

Comment: Have you the real script http://www.example.com/my-great-article.php or binary executable my-great-article?

Answer (score 0):

Redirect is not required, you would need only rewrite. If you have http://www.example.com/my-great-article.php, that interprets the $_GET["lang"] for language detection in .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

In the first set: $2 is language backreference, $1 is script filename capturing such as my-great-article.php.

In the second set,  $1 is language abbreviation like en, fr, cn, it, es, jp, de, ...

This set of rules do this:

```
http://www.example.com/en/my-great-article.php => /my-great-article.php?lang=en
http://www.example.com/en => /index.php?lang=en
http://www.example.com/en/ => /index.php?lang=en
```